# Ruby Post Request with Basic Auth and Multiple Params

Tags: ruby, rest-client, curb, typhoeus

I'm having a ridiculously hard time doing something presumably simple...

I am trying to run a simple POST request in ruby. I've looked at curb, typhoeus, rest-client, etc... The post request has basic auth (via api key) and two params...

I have the command written out in curl form below, which works perfectly.

```
curl -X POST https://api.com/v1 -u any_string:abc123 -d var1="help" -d var2="me"
```

Can anyone help me translate this into ruby? I don't mind using typhoeus, curb, etc... as long as it works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've use this tool before with some success. https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/

Your curl statement generates this Ruby code.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("https://api.com/v1")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.basic_auth("any_string", "abc123")
request.set_form_data(
  "var1" => "help",
  "var2" => "me",
)

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https") do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

# response.code
# response.body
```

There are about a million different HTTP request libraries in Ruby but sometimes its just simple to write it in Net HTTP (Net HTTP is included in the Ruby Standard Library).

Answer (score 3):

[rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) is also pretty concise for this.

```
require 'rest-client'

RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: 'https://api.com/v1',
                            user: 'any_string', password: 'abc123',
                            payload: {var1: 'help', var2: 'me'}
)
```

Comment: Thank you A B - I was getting 401 errors because I wasn't passing the user parameter.